# Load content on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a team page for  website. 
A picture of each member is laid out in a "grid" type of view. There are two boxes below this grid with some content.
Box 1: Basic div with some text.
Box 2: Div with some sample % or value based bars.

When a website visitor click on a team members picture, the boxes will get populated with information about that member.
Box 1: Description about the person and maybe some links.
Box 2: The data in the bars  will change to values that represent the skills the member has.

Can this be done in any way other than: pagify.js?

EDIT*** (16 Aug 2013)
The first part of my question is sovled.
For the second box, I wanted to make a animated skill bar like the ones here http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-skill-bar-animation/
How can i update these dynamically?

EDIT*** (17 Aug 2013)
I managed to implement this features :). Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: Yes...attach a click event to each picture. Then you can use a custom data attributes as a picture identifier, start an AJAX call, and populate on complete.

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are developers. (My own does not require AJAX.) If you want a solution, please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript/jQuery onClick show and hide events should do what you want.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp - basics
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-show-and-hide-example/ - workinging example
http://www.goldensearch.net/content/tutorials/show-hidden-content-with-javascript.php - pure javascript :-)

If this isn't what you're looking for we (or at least I) will need more detail in the question.

Comment: For the second box, i wanted to make a animated skill bar like the ones [HERE](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-skill-bar-animation/)
How can i update these dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could use AJAX to achieve this behaviour but as long as we're not talking about thousands of team members, a simpler but yet powerful solution is to hide all detailed information and only show them for an active member the user clicked on.

**Update**: (Working version on [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kfKw/) [http://jsfiddle.net/9kfKw/])

**HTML** (Example)

```
<ul id="members">
    <li>Member 1</li>
    <li>Member 2</li>
</ul>

<div id="details">
    <div>
        <div class="left">
            <p>Some Info about Member 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Some more Info Member 1..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="left">
            <p>Some Info about Member 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Some more Info about Member2..</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#members li').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('#details > div').hide().eq(index).show();
    });
});
```

**Demo**

Find a working version on [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kfKw/) (http://jsfiddle.net/9kfKw/)

Comment: Thanks Pex, Yes I'm talking about a fairly small team size (under 20). I'm gonna try this one and see if it works for me. Cheers

Comment: Great @teejay - just tell me if there are questions left on the solution ;)

Comment: Hey, this actually works quite well, but unfortuntely my design does not allow me the kind of implementation. However its almost perfect.

Comment: I have added some more info regarding the second box. Any possible help on this?